# Saving data from Textboxes into a local File

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create an UWP App with Visual Studio which saves and reads 2 Textboxes and 1 DatePicker into an File, but I have no idea how to do that.
Saving the data should work now, that is my method:

```
        public async Task SaveDataInLocalFile(KalenderClass data)
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
        using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream.AsStream());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        }
    }
```

This is how my safe button looks like:

```
        private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
        kc.Termin = TerminTextBlock.Text;
        kc.Person = PersonTextBlock.Text;
        kc.Datum = DatePicker1.Date;
        await SaveDataInLocalFile(kc);



    }
```

And this ist how my read button looks like:

```
                private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = await GetDataFromLocalFile();
        TerminTextBlock.Text = data.Termin;

    }
```

The problem now is that the xml File is serialized and I dont know how to deserialize ist.

**New save and read method:**

```
        public async Task SaveDataInLocalFile(KalenderClass data)
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        TerminTextbox.Text = localFolder.Path;
        var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
        using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream.AsStreamForWrite(), data);
        }
    }

        public async Task<KalenderClass> GetDataFromLocalFile()
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
        using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            var data = serializer.ReadObject(stream.AsStream()) as KalenderClass;
            return data;
        }
    }
```

**Save and read button:**

```
        private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
        kc.Termin = TerminTextbox.Text;
        kc.Person = PersonTextbox.Text;
        kc.Datum = DatePicker1.Date;
        await SaveDataInLocalFile(kc);
        showDialog("Daten wurden in Daten geschrieben");

    }

        private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KalenderClass data = await GetDataFromLocalFile();
        PersonTextbox.Text = data.Termin;

    }
```

Comment: Hi, are you creating a native UWP app or a desktop bridge app? Is your `SaveDataInLocalFile` method written in the class library or UWP project?

Comment: I am creating an UWP app. Its written in my Kalender.xaml.cs File.

Comment: `ApplicationData` is a class under the `Windows.Storage` namespace. You can try to add `using Windows.Storage;` in the header of the xaml.cs file to introduce this namespace

Comment: Thank you, now it can find ApplicationData! I edited my button, is that how it works? And where can I find the saved data.

Answer (score 1):

The full name of `ApplicationData` is `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData`.

If you want to enter only `ApplicationData`, you need to add a reference to the namespace in the file header:

```cs
using Windows.Storage;

...

var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

---

If you want to know the saved file path, you can use this code:

```cs
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string path = localFolder.Path;
```

You can break the program during debugging and check the value of path.

**Update**

*Deserialize method*

```cs
public async Task<KalenderClass> GetDataFromLocalFile()
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
    using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        var data = serializer.Deserialize(stream.AsStream()) as KalenderClass;
        return data;
    }
}
```

---

**Update2**

The problem lies in `DateTimeOffset`, `XmlSerializer` currently has limited support for `DateTimeOffset`, you can consider using `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`.

```cs
public async Task SaveDataInLocalFile(KalenderClass data)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
    using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream.AsStreamForWrite(), data);
    }
}

public async Task<KalenderClass> GetDataFromLocalFile()
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
    using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        var data = serializer.ReadObject(stream.AsStream()) as KalenderClass;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I created the variable but somehow I cant find the value of the variable. I checked in autos oder local but cant find it.

Comment: I just want to check if it really safes the data.

Comment: Hello, The directory structure of the application local folder looks like this: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Packages\{package name}\LocalState`, saving data to the application folder is commonly used way of doing. Generally speaking, the folder is not visible to the user. If you have additional requirements for data security, you can encrypt your data.

Comment: Okay, thank you very very much! Now I understood everything so far, but how do I deserialize the xml file now? Because I want to have an read button to read everything in my XML File

Comment: Hello, I have modified the answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have also modified my question because my read button still does not work

Comment: Hello, I did not reproduce this problem in the test. Can you provide the complete code for us to test?

Comment: Hello, the problem is `DateTimeOffset`, you can use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`, I have written the method in the answer. In addition, about the code you added, you can write it in the question description.

Comment: Thank you! But somehow it still does not read the XML file. Is everything fine with my read button? Im trying to set the data from the XML file to the TerminTextBlock, you can see it in my question but it still does not work. And thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi, Don't worry, did you receive any error when running the code? Have you tried to open the saved XML file (opened through Explorer) to view the specific content?

Comment: No I still dont know where to find the file. And no I didnt get any error. I tried string path = localFolder.Path;, but I didnt get any value from the variable path.

Comment: Can you get the information of `localFolder.Path` when debugging? Maybe you can try to print the path information in the output console (`Debug.WriteLine()`), or add a temporary TextBlock to the page to display it (`TempTextBlock.Text = localFolder.Path`).

Comment: Okay, now I get the error, that there was an issue error deserializing the object of type Studienarbeit.KalenderClass. The token '>' was expected but found 'K'. Line 1, position 3.. And yes I found out where it is saved.

Comment: Hello, did you replace the serializers in the `GetData` and `SetData` methods with `DataContractSerializer`? You can check the XML file you get to see how it differs from ordinary XML documents

Comment: yes I did replace them. I modified my question. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, can you show the data of the generated XAML file? Conversion failure may be caused by incorrect data structure

Answer (score 0):

Kalender.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Storage;

// Die Elementvorlage "Leere Seite" wird unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238 dokumentiert.

namespace Studienarbeit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Eine leere Seite, die eigenständig verwendet oder zu der innerhalb eines Rahmens navigiert werden kann.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Kalender : Page
    {
        
        //List<KalenderClass> ls;


        public Kalender()
        {
            
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        public async Task SaveDataInLocalFile(KalenderClass data)
        {
 
            var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
            using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream.AsStream());
                serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
            }
        }

        private async void showDialog(string message)
        {
            var window = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Achtung", message);
            await window.ShowAsync();
        }

        private void ButtonStartseite_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ButtonStartseite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        private void TerminTextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
            kc.Termin = TerminTextBlock.Text;
            kc.Person = PersonTextBlock.Text;
            kc.Datum = DatePicker1.Date;
            await SaveDataInLocalFile(kc);
            showDialog("Daten wurden in Daten geschrieben");

        }


        private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = await GetDataFromLocalFile();
            TerminTextBlock.Text = data.Termin;

        }

        public async Task<KalenderClass> GetDataFromLocalFile()
        {
            var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var dataFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KalenderClass));
            using (var stream = await dataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                var data = serializer.Deserialize(stream.AsStream()) as KalenderClass;
                return data;
            }
        }

        private void TerminTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

KalenderClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Studienarbeit
{
    public class KalenderClass
    {
        public string Termin { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Datum { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```